# Read a file character by character and pass them to an array in C

Tags: c, file, matrix, 2d

I have to parse a matrix from a file which first line characters are the rows and the cols count and the next lines are the matrix values.

---

The file contains:

```
3 3
R R B
B G G
G B R
```

I wrote the following code, but it crashes.

```
char** readMatrix(FILE *file) {
    char *array;
    int el = 0;
    while (fscanf_s(file, "%s", array) != EOF) {
    array[el] = array;
    el++;
    }
    const int n = array[0] - '0', m = array[1] - '0';
    char** matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(char));
    }
    int k = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = array[k];
            ++k;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

**The size of the matrix is different for the different files. How is it possible to declare a char array without knowing the size?**

Comment: Use `realloc()` to glow arrays as needed.

Comment: You need to dynamically allocate it, or use Variable Length Arrays. But currently you’re just using `array` without setting any value for it which is undefined behavior. Turn your compiler’s warnings to max.

Comment: `array[el] = array` What is that doing? Not only is `array` an unintialised pointer and thus likely the cause of the crash but it's very strange to stored a reference to the array in itself. Parse integers using `%d` instead.

Comment: array[el] = array -> I am trying to assign the input value to array element .

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if your FILE is not NULL ( it may crash cause of this )

```
if ( file == NULL ) {
    printf("Error"); 
    exit(1);
}
```

Then you need to be sure that your FILE's pointer is pointing at the start of the file :

```
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

If your rule is : 'The first line always contains two positive integer separate by a space and ending the line just after the second uint', then you can read them like this :

```
int dim_x = 0, dim_y = 0 ;
fscanf(file, "%d %d\n", &dim_x, &dim_y);
if(dim_x <= 0 || dim_y <= 0){
    printf("Impossible to get correct the correct dimensions");
    exit(1);
}
```

Then you can read your file line by line to have the correct data.

There is many variation to read your file. Assuming that any datas of your file are single characters spaced by 1 space or 1 backline, you can loop like this :

```
    char ** matrix = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * nbr_y);

    for(int line = 0 ; line < nbr_y ; line ++){
        matrix[line] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * nbr_x); 
        for(int data_x_index = 0 ; data_x_index < nbr_x ; data_x_index ++){
            fscanf(f, "%c", &matrix[line][data_x_index]); //Read and stock the character direclty in the matrix
            fseek(f, 1, SEEK_CUR); // Go to the next character to read
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < nbr_y ; i ++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < nbr_x ; j ++){
            printf("%c ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Caution : This version is not checking if the text is well formated and if the dimensions are correct !

Comment: It is reading only the first line characters of the matrix.

Comment: Have your print a space before the line break in your .txt

Comment: You can try to debug like this : ```for(int data_x_index = 0 ; data_x_index < nbr_x ; data_x_index ++){
            fscanf(f, "%c", &matrix[line][data_x_index]); //Read and stock the character direclty in the matrix
            printf("Character read at %d, %d : %d\n", line, data_x_index, matrix[line][data_x_index]);
            fseek(f, 1, SEEK_CUR); // Go to the next character to read
        }
```